# About Cyclic Permutation

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I studied math, and I come up with this problem.
There are two permutations A and B and a integer M.
We say A almost equal to B if we can make from A to B doing following operations.
-1 Choose a M-length segment of the permutation A.
-2 Perform a cyclic shift on it towards the right.(So,if sub segment is "1 2 3 4 5"(m=5), then after this operation , it will be "5 1 2 3 4".)

Question : Does A almost equal to B?

I think it is typical , but I couldn't find the answer.
How to solve it?(not brute force!)

number of elements in the permutation<=10^5

example

A "1 2 3"
B "2 3 1"
m=2
answer　YES
explain　"1 2 3"->"2 1 3"->"2 3 1"

Comment: Conjecture: if the permutations have length m, then check whether they're rotations of each other. Otherwise, if m is odd, then check whether they have the same parity. If m is even and less than the permutation length, then they're always almost equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof of my conjecture. Let `n` be the length of the permutations and `m` be the length of the windows that we are allowed to rotate, where `1 ≤ m ≤ n`. Permutations `P` and `Q` are *almost equal* if there exists a sequence of window rotations that transforms `P` into `Q`. Almost equality is an equivalence relation. Here's the claimed characterization of the equivalence classes.

```
(1) m = 1: P almost equals Q if and only if P = Q
(2) m = n: P almost equals Q if and only if they're rotations of each other
(3) 1 < m < n, m odd: P almost equals Q if and only if they have the same parity
(4) 1 < m < n, n even: P almost equals Q
```

The first two claims are obvious. As for `(3)`, the necessity of the parity condition follows from the fact that rotating a window of odd length is an even permutation.

The meat of the argument here is to find an algorithm for when `n = m + 1 ≥ 4`, since in general, we can use an algorithm similar to insertion sort to transform `P` so that all but the last `m + 1` elements match `Q`, and specifically, the case `(n, m) = (3, 2)` can be solved by inspection. In case `m` is even, we ensure further that the transformation matches the parity of `Q`, by rotating the last `m` elements once if necessary. (For `m` odd, we just assume equal parities.)

We need a technique for moving fewer than `m` elements at once. Suppose that the state is as follows.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, ..., m, m + 1
```

Rotate the second window `m - 1` times (i.e., once in reverse).

```
1, 3, 4, ..., m, m + 1, 2
```

Rotate the first window `m - 1` times.

```
3, 4, ..., m, m + 1, 1, 2
```

Second, twice.

```
3, 2, 4, ..., m, m + 1, 1
3, 1, 2, 4, ..., m, m + 1
```

We've succeeded in rotating the first three elements. This suffices in combination with conjugation by rotations to "insertion sort" the first `m - 1` elements of `Q` into place. The other two are in the right order by the parity match.